Can we have "computed" properties in Lit web components?
Vue.js has a feature called Computed Properties. These are properties (values) that are recomputed whenever their reactive dependencies change. They are useful for simplifying code and for caching expensive computations, as in this example from their official documentation:

Why do we need caching? Imagine we have an expensive computed property list, which requires looping through a huge array and doing a lot of computations. Then we may have other computed properties that in turn depend on list. Without caching, we would be executing list's getter many more times than necessary! In cases where you do not want caching, use a method call instead.

Does Lit Web Components support something similar?

Are you looking for something like this:https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#repeat?

and if you want to calculate something based on reactive property change then you can use https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#willupdate willupdate Lifecyle also however you need to implement cache machism.

@Chellappanவ This last comment sounds like an answer, maybe you should write it as such.

Added as answer @Denilson

As mentioned in the documentation, use willUpdate to compute property values that depend on other reactive properties
willUpdate(changedProperties: PropertyValues<this>) {
  // only need to check changed properties for an expensive computation.
  if (changedProperties.has('firstName') || changedProperties.has('lastName')) {
    this.sha = computeSHA(`${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`);
  }
}

render() {
  return html`SHA: ${this.sha}`;
}

